Summatory function floor notation
On a recent answer about arithmetic functions, I often use quantities like $F(\lfloor n/i \rfloor)$, where $F$ is the summatory function of $f$, i.e. $F(n) = \sum_{i \le n} f(i)$.
Is it cleaner to extend $F$ to the real domain by defining $F(x) = \sum_{i \le x} f(i)$, equivalently $F(x) := F(\lfloor x \rfloor)$? This lets me leave off lots of floor symbols that may be distracting, but when I want to do counting for how many $i$ have equal $F(n/i)$ because the input is actually floored, I have to introduce them again, so it could be more confusing going back and forth. What I can also do is specify all divisions as floor divisions, but this likely serves to make things even more confusing.

If you're asking if $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\lfloor x\rfloor} f(i)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^x f(i)$$ then yes this is true. Many functions such as Mertens function $$M(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x \mu(n)$$ are typically defined without use of the floor function. I don't understand your comment about having to reintroduce the floor function.

@StevenClark it is shown in my linked answer. Basically for my simplified counting of the Dirichlet hyperbola method, there is a term like F(floor(n/i)), and for many large values of i this argument floor(n/i) turns out to be the same. So I can write F(n/i) but for precise counting I need to reintroduce the floor.

Yes, it is very common to use functions like
$$
F(x) = \sum_{n\le x} f(n)
$$
when summing arithmetic functions. Such summatory functions take a real number as input, and they are step functions—constant on every interval $[n,n+1)$ with jump discontinuities of size $f(n)$ at $x=n$ (unless $f(n)=0$). (It's also usually implicit that the sum is over only positive integers $n$.)
The notation $\sum_{n\le x}$ is preferred to $\sum_{n=1}^x$, since the latter notation has connotations that the upper bound should be an integer.

Do you think in the context of my linked answer if would reduce confusion? Or is it clearer to be explicit with all the floors? Or does it not matter.
